# How to prove that predicates are not equivalent?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Given following predicates:

$$
F_1 = (\forall x)(F(x) \leftrightarrow G(x)) \text{ and } F_2 = (\forall x)F(x) \leftrightarrow (\forall x)G(x)
$$

I think that they are not equivalent, but if it possible to prove that?

Comment: Use "x is Even" and "x Is Odd"

Comment: Or $F(x)=x$, $G(x)=\lnot x$.

Comment: @user10354138 - do you mean that $F(x)$ must be $x$? If so, it is wrong: $x$ is a variable and not a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a domain with exactly two objects, one of which has property $F$ but not property $G$, while the other one has property $G$, but not property $F$.

Then $(\forall x)(F(x) \leftrightarrow G(x))$ is clearly false, but since $(\forall x)F(x)$ and $(\forall x)G(x)$ are both false as well, $(\forall x)F(x) \leftrightarrow (\forall x)G(x)$ ends up being true

Answer (score 0):

Consider $a,b\in\mathbb R$.
$$\forall x(ax + b = 0) \leftrightarrow \forall x (a = b = 0)$$
certainly holds, but
$$\forall x (ax + b = 0 \leftrightarrow a = b = 0)$$
does not!